# How do I recreate NoRouteToHostException scenario?

Tags: exception, tcp, client

Existing Java code (client side of TCP client-server) recently encountered a NoRouteToHostException for the first time. It did not handle the exception correctly. I've adjusted the code to handle that exception. How can I create a NoRouteToHostException scenario in a lab environment so I can test that my fix handles the exception correctly?

Answer (score 0):

throw new NoRouteToHostException

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to duplicate the problem in software. I'm looking for a way to duplicate the problem by doing something to my network so that I can actually experience the error.